# PowerPoint command like insert slide or apply theme equivalent on Office javascript API

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing a PowerPoint add-in and in future, it will be publish in Office Store. But it is VSTO project (C# and winforms) which could not be publish. Based on my search, it must be Office Web Add-in project (manifest xml and web pages).

I'm trying to convert my development from VSTO to Office Web Add-in but some of functionalities like open presentation, insert slide and apply theme aren't found on the Office.js.

Is there equivalent functions in Office.js? or other way?

Hopefully someone share their ideas about it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check the section devoted to Office Javascript:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js

Comment: I checked it. So far, maybe Microsoft is currently working the API for PowerPoint. Thanks a lot Steve.

Comment: Yes, the javascript API is a work in progress, especially so for PPT, which is one of the last Office apps to get this technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently no way to execute these actions (insert slide, apply theme, open document) in PowerPoint using Web Add-ins. PowerPoint currently only leverages a limited set of APIs.