# Insert slide in Powerpoint presentation via Office Js

Tags: javascript, office-js, powerpoint-addins

I am implementing a Powerpoint add-in via Office JS and I wonder whether the following scenario is feasible or not.

1) Populate add-in's Task Pane with slide templates

2) Click on one of the slide templates and inject it in the presentation via Office JS

Comment: Please add some detail about your #1. I don't understand what you mean by populating the task pane with slide templates.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for the reply. I have spent time investigating and I concluded that (2) is not currently supported from Office JS. This is a similar issue I found. For (1) I will find a work around to this. But my main concern is (2). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060429/powerpoint-command-like-insert-slide-or-apply-theme-equivalent-on-office-javascr

Answer (score 0):

you can add the script lab code in your PowerPoint from office add-ins store

[image]